# How much faster is advanced UAV frequency compared to regular UAV?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

It is said that the Advanced UAV pointstreak is similar to the regular UAV but it shows players on the map and the direction with an increased frequency.  In other words, it shows their position more often than a regular UAV.

How much faster is the refresh frequency for the Advanced UAV compared to the "normal" UAV?

Comment: It also shows their facing - they are displayed as arrows instead of dots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a video of an advanced UAV, as you can see it is a much faster than the second video and shows the direction the enemy is facing.

[Advanced UAV](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D8Q2fIfwwNk)

[Regular UAV](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZ8eFdKAdU0)

Comment: Can it be that calling an extra UAV while a UAV is in the air turns the whole thing into an Advanced UAV? I have experienced something like this in a game, but I couldn't tell if it was my added UAV, or someone else unleashing the AUAV.

Answer (score 4):

Advanced UAV is real time in-game or "on map" movement. UAV is a sweep based radar like ping that updates every 1.5 seconds or so.